# Query Sorting issue when sorting by Aliased Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have calculating geo distance procedure in SQL Server, but it's have aliased column and can not work sorting property true;

```
DECLARE
    @GEO1 GEOGRAPHY,
    @LAT VARCHAR(10),
    @LONG VARCHAR(10)

SET @LAT = '41.000000'
SET @LONG = '30.000000'

SET @geo1 = geography::Point(@LAT, @LONG, 4326)

SELECT 
    LOC_ID, LOC_NAME,
    LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, (@geo1.STDistance(geography::Point(ISNULL(LAT,0), ISNULL(LONG, 0), 4326))) / 1000), 4) AS DISTANCE
FROM
    Konum
WHERE 
   (@geo1.STDistance(geography::Point(ISNULL(LAT,0), ISNULL(LONG,0), 4326))) / 1000 < 10
```

I tried

```
DECLARE
    @GEO1 GEOGRAPHY,
    @LAT VARCHAR(10),
    @LONG VARCHAR(10)

SET @LAT = '41.329867'
SET @LONG = '36.264149'

SET @geo1= geography::Point(@LAT, @LONG, 4326)

SELECT 
    LOC_ID, LOC_NAME,
    LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, (@geo1.STDistance(geography::Point(ISNULL(LAT, 0), ISNULL(LONG, 0), 4326))) / 1000), 4) AS DISTANCE
FROM
    Konum
WHERE 
    (@geo1.STDistance(geography::Point(ISNULL(LAT, 0), ISNULL(LONG, 0), 4326))) / 1000 < 30
ORDER BY 
    DISTANCE ASC -- <=
```

But return aliased varchar column

```
1.2
1.3
11.5 <= Not like
2.8
9.7
```

I tried:

```
CAST(DISTANCE AS INT)
```

But SMSS throws an error "invalid column name 'DISTANCE'" because it is a column alias.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Thx for replay, float value sorting 1,3-1,6-11-2.5 <= wrong returned.

Comment: Alias (Virtual) column not accept Left,Len,Cast etc.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your distance column is currently a string and is therefore being sorted as such. Remove the string conversion (`LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR`) and it will sort it correctly.

```
DECLARE @GEO1 GEOGRAPHY, @LAT VARCHAR(10) = '41.329867', @LONG VARCHAR(10) = '36.264149'

SET @geo1= geography::Point(@LAT, @LONG, 4326)

SELECT LOC_ID, LOC_NAME
  , (@geo1.STDistance(geography::Point(ISNULL(LAT,0), 
  ISNULL(LONG,0), 4326)))/1000 AS DISTANCE
FROM Konum
WHERE (@geo1.STDistance(geography::Point(ISNULL(LAT,0), ISNULL(LONG,0), 4326)))/1000 < 30
ORDER BY DISTANCE ASC
```